# simple wine issue

Tags: installation, software-center, wine, package-management

I have a wine issue. I am trying to install wine with 'ubuntu software center' but it wont let me. I recieve this pop-up and do not know what it means. please help.

**Package dependencies cannot be resolved**

This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.

**Details**

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

wine1.4: PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.15.7.2~) but 1.16.10ubuntu1 is to be installed

```
     Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but 2.17-0ubuntu5 is to be installed

     Depends: wine1.4-amd64 (= 1.4.1-0ubuntu5) but 1.4.1-0ubuntu5 is to be installed

     Depends: wine1.4-i386 (= 1.4.1-0ubuntu5) but it is a virtual package
```

Any help would be great

Answer (score 0):

I am now able to down `wine`. I found that I had a bunch of old `wine` files on my computer that I was unable to delete.

I logged in as root and deleted every `wine` file that I had. I did this by using the YouTube walkthrough [Ubuntu 13.04 - Enabling Root](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jesri_T60F0).